# Motorcycle(Yamaha Fzs 2014) won't start even with kick after sitting for 4 months

Tags: motorcycle, starting, yamaha

My motorcycle (Yamaha Fzs 2014) has been sitting idle for the last 4 months. Now I can't start my motorcycle even with kick. How do I start my motorcycle?

Comment: First is the fuel old? Fresh fuel would be a good start..

Comment: Yes the fuel is old.

Comment: So first step is to change the fuel : from the tank to the carburettor so it is all fresh- then try to start it... It may be your opportunity to change the plug, air filter and oil as well.